# Making CRUD app, the "create" part isn't working

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, pg-promise

Well, it was this afternoon.

I'm creating a news aggregator that connects to `newsapi`, but one of the more important features is giving users the ability to submit their own articles.

The create view renders, and after plugging information in the boxes and hitting submit I'm presented with an empty {  }---

more importantly, the info is not added to the database.

Because I did get it working earlier, I figured I made a mistake at some point after that caused the problem.

Any thoughts? I've been looking at this for over an hour and I'm stumped.

server.js :

```
// CREATE get
app.get('/home/create', (request, response) => {
  response.render('create');
})

// CREATE 
app.post('/home/create', urlencodedParser, (request, response) => {
  const articleNew = request.body;
  Article.createArticle(articleNew).then(article => {
    response.redirect('/home');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    response.send(error);
  })
});
```

News.js:

```
// require database setup to use pg-Promise
const pgp = require('pg-promise')({});

const Article = {};

const connectionURL = "postgres://localhost:5432/news_app";

// new database connection
const db = pgp(connectionURL);

Article.createArticle = article => {
  return db.any('INSERT INTO user_articles(name, author, title, description, url) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING id', [article.name,  article.author,  article.title, article.description, article.url]);
};

module.exports = Article;
```

create.ejs

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/home/create" method="post">
  <fieldset>

<!-- Button -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Table name: user_articles :

> id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
>
> name VARCHAR(255),
>
> author VARCHAR(255),
>
> title VARCHAR(255),
>
> description VARCHAR(255),
>
> url VARCHAR(255)
>
> );

Comment: Have you stepped through the function?  Do you know what data is actually being delivered to your server?

Comment: @Legman Hey, just ran it through the debugger, it said something about the parameters in News.ejs being faulty. I removed the $6, made some changes, but still nothing. I then shortened Article.createArticle(etc) in News to what I had earlier, then it worked. Upon trying the original Article.createArticles that I had (with the removed $6) it worked. I'm sorry if this is a bit wordy, I'm pretty tired. But thanks. I think this might've convinced me that the debugger's pretty damn useful.